# How can I know the Linux IO operation history?

Tags: linux, io

I want to query the Ubuntu Linux I/O operation history of a partition, such as `rm` and `mv`. The file system of the partition is ext4.

When I use the `Linux, IO operation, history` as the keyword search in Google, most of the results are IO monitor; that's not what I want.

So is there any method to make it?

Comment: I don't think Linux keeps a history.

Comment: Try "file alteration monitor" as google search. There are some tools based on `inotify`

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to read [the source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/extundelete/code/ci/master/tree/src/) of [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/), as it seems to be able to parse the `ext[34]` journal data.